# Tridion 2013 - DXA - Render Entity

Tags: 2013, dxa, 2013-sp1

In our implementation there is one Main Region, where previously items where render like it is on following image

[image]

During implementation of certain View, we identify that there should be another region, but in that case, we had issues with html. So we decided to use only Main region and to render all items there.
But some items should have its own div while others should remain in the main.

I made following code, and it works ok
[image]

I can move some logic to the Controller, but I would like to know is there any other solution.

In the case of region, we can pass information such  as using of `@Html.DxaRegions(exclude: "name of the region")`

[image]

So is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create an `AssetGroup` region, so for that you should create a region view:

```html
@model RegionModel
<div class="menuAssetsGroup" @Html.DxaRegionMarkup()>
    @Html.DxaEntities()
</div>
```

Don't change the `Main` region view, the `GeneralPage` view will automatically be adding your `AssetGroup` region when there is content on the page in that region.

To get the content into the `AssetGroup` region, make sure you configure your `Asset` Component Template to be in the `AssetGroup` region by supplying this new region name in the Component Template metadata, as described here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-8714ED2D-4F98-4433-80DD-6A4FE2E6EC64

In case you need your `AssetGroup` region to be in a fixed place in the page layout (not depending on Component Presentation order), you can change the `GeneralPage` view and add your new region by calling:

```
@Html.DxaRegion("AssetGroup")
```

And making sure to exclude it from all the other `@Html.DxaRegion` calls.

*Please note it would be advised to make all these changes in a separate module, rather than changing the core views. See these two blog posts for some more information on how to create modules in DXA:*

- https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/02/creating-custom-dxa-module-s
- https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/03/modules-in-the-content-manager